# Can a Wild Shaped Druid use weapons to attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, druid, wild-shape

If a 5th edition druid would transformed into an ape or creature like an ape that has has opposable thumbs like a human could they then use a weapon to attack with such as a great sword or dagger instead of the Beast usual melee attack?