# What determines if a Wild Shaped Druid/Rogue can use a finesse weapon to gain Sneak Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, wild-shape, sneak-attack

A Druid/Rogue multiclass gains access to Wild Shape and Sneak Attack.

While Wild Shaped, a character gets access to most features it has normally. Sneak Attack is one of those features.

I am aware that the basic Ape has a ranged attack that qualifies for Sneak Attack. I was hoping to learn of the other means of applying Sneak Attack: finesse weapons.

Which Beasts can the Druid/Rogue turn into that can actually use finesse weapons like a Dagger? What determines if a Beast can use such weapons?

Whether or not the Beasts keep weapon proficiency is another question, but best left for another post. (Wild Shape only mentions Skill and Save proficiencies, iirc.)

Comment: Related: "[Could a Druid/Pact Blade Warlock use a Pact Blade while in Wild Shape form?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90430)" and "[Can a druid in Ape wildshape use weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96950)" and "[Can a Druid cast the Flame Blade spell, then use the blade while Wild Shaped?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142998)" and "[Can a Wild Shaped Druid use weapons to attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109905)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The DM determines if a beast is of the appropriate anatomy to wield a particular weapon.

There is no published guidance on what weapons can be used by what beasts. The *Player's Handbook* uses a phrase regarding mounts that is helpful here:

> A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an *appropriate anatomy* can serve as a mount, using the following rules.

When we ask the question, "can I ride this beast?", the DM determines if the beast has the *appropriate anatomy* to be ridden as a mount. It's the same deal here. A little tiny bat probably cannot wield a shortsword, but maybe a medium sized ape could. It is up to the DM to determine if the wildshaped form has the *appropriate anatomy* to wield your weapon of choice.

Answer (score 4):

Very few beasts have hands, effectively, and can thus use weapons at all.  Apes, *maybe* raccoons, octopodes, etc.  So it's not really a big issue with a lot of choices.  If the druid has some special weapon(s) made that they can use in animal form, that might work, but you're well into homebrew territory already there, so the DM will be able to decide as he likes.

There are a few monsters, mostly smaller ones, that use Dexterity for their natural attacks; I count those as "finesse" and allow sneak attack to work with them.

Comment: Could you give an example of such beasts that apply Dex to attack? This is the first I've heard of them.

Comment: @Axoren The [eagle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/eagle) is an example